# Barra de progreso con datos de SQL

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy intentando hacer una barra de progreso, que tenga por ejemplo un limite de capacidad de 4000. En lo cual llenaría ese progreso con un `count` de una consulta de SQL. El tema es que no se como hacerlo, importe de bootstrap el siguiente codigo:

```
<div class="progress" role="progressbar" aria-label="Example with label" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
  <div class="progress-bar" style="width:50%">'.$resultado['Count'].'</div>
</div>
```

la variable trae el numero de una consulta SQL, eso no hay problema, el tema es como hago para que calculo el numero por ejemplo 4000 como 100%? y ponerlo en el width?

Si pudieran guiarme por donde debería investigar o como hacerlo, agradecería mucho

Comment: Te recomendaría que vieses el siguiente tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_progressbar.asp seguro que te será de gran ayuda

Comment: Me sirvio muchísimo la guia, ya lo pude hacer!  muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes asignar a `aria-valuemax` el valor del resultado de tu consulta. Como tú indicas en este caso 4000.

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="4000"></div>
</div>
```

Luego, la documentación indica:

> "El .progress-bar requiere un estilo en línea, una clase de utilidad o
> CSS personalizado para establecer su ancho."

Entonces el `width` tiene que ser dinámico de acuerdo a tu valor de la consulta SQL que ya lo pusiste en `aria-valuemax` y al valor que está en curso "completado" de progreso.

```
$('.progress-bar').each(function() {
  let min = $(this).attr('aria-valuemin');
  let max = $(this).attr('aria-valuemax');
  let now = $(this).attr('aria-valuenow');
  let siz = (now-min)*100/(max-min);
  $(this).css('width', siz +'%');
});
```

Comment: leyendo mi duda nuevamente, me di cuenta que lo exprese mal, el 4000 seria el 100%, el limite. El count de la consulta suele tener numeros entre 1500 y 3000, la idea es que se vea ese crecimiento en la barra como tope "4000 como 100%"